# Is it possible to update database structure using the schema.yml in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have some columns that I want to add in one of the tables from my database. I added those columns in my schema.yml, so my question is; is it possible in Symfony 1.4 to apply those changes to my db using the schema.yml?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Doctrine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No You have to manually update the database, using phpmyadmin or mysql command line or any other tools.

You might use doctrine or propel as ORM but on

For example if its Propel:

```
php symfony propel-build-model
```

It only sets getters and setters.

Might be my answer be a bit late, but might help someone in future.